# Map not built in slam_gmapping

Tags: navigation, sicklms, rosaria, gmapping, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build a map using slam_gmapping. My platform is ActivMedia MobileRobots Powerbot equipped with sonar sensors and SICKLMS laser range finder. I am using the `ROSARIA` package to interact with the robot and to get the odometry data. Then I am using `sicktoolbox_wrapper` package in order to interface with the laser range finder. I have tested each node separately to make sure that the data I want is being published over the respective topics. I tested this with ROSARIA by running `rostopic echo /RosAria/pose` and also by writing code to subscribe to that topic. Similarly I ran `rostopic echo scan` to see that the laser range finder is really working and I can see the data being streamed. I also tried to visualize it on `rviz` but I got an error saying that the frame `[laser]` does not exist. I don't know how to fix this but since I saw the data being publish over `rostopic` I assumed that the laser scanner was set up and ready to be used.

So I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) and built a bag by moving my robot around the room. The bag was created "successfully" since no errors had been given. At this point I wanted to verify that all the nodes were running appropriately and the right publishing and subcribing was being made. So I ran `rqt_graph` and got this: [C:\fakepath\setup rqt.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14225269666729206.png). From what I know of ROS, everything is set up according to the tutorial, having the `slam_gmapping` node being subscribed to both `/scan` and `/tf` (this is the only difference from the tutorial: in the tutorial `base_scan` was used while my topic from sicktoolbox_wrapper was just `scan`).

I thought that having all this set up would result in a successful build of the map. However, when I ran gmapping and replayed the bag that I had recorded I got this error:

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_link at time 1.42253e+09 according to authority /play_1422525800501358444
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 260 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-tf2-0.4.12-0precise-20141016-1214/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

When the bag stopped replaying and I attempted to save the map, no map was saved and it just kept "Waiting for map". Also, during the process of 'building' the map, I tried to visualize it on rviz but again, I got a warning message telling me "Map is not found".

Can anyone help me identify the fault and explain what is going on? Thanks!

EDIT

From what I can see from this `rqt_graph` [C:\fakepath\slam_gmapping.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14225331029416947.png) is that the node slam_gmapping is publishing on the topic `/map`. I have added a Map on `rviz` and set its topic to `/map` but in the Status I'm getting a Warning saying: No Map Received. [C:\fakepath\Rviz Slam_gmapping.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14225331293912349.png)How is this possible?

EDIT

I run the sicktoolbox_wrapper node as follows:

```
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:=/dev/ttyS1 _baud:=38400
```

I run the rosaria node as follows:

```
rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyS0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202020/map-not-built-in-slam_gmapping/) by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-02-05**:
the most likely reason is that your tf is not defined and connected to the base_laser_link. Can you check your tf tree for connection between the base_link with your laser sensor. Because the link is not published you are not able to see the laser data and also the map.

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-06**:
Hi Alex,

I am using this transform code (see [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7cntsl924o4ekh/transform.cpp?dl=0)) and I have seen the following tf frames (see [frames.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jeg9srfc46ufu7k/frames.pdf?dl=0).

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-06**:
The problem I'm facing now is that I can, technically, see a map being built. BUT the laser readings are seen jumping around on the grid in rviz, thus creating duplicates of the same mapped area. Do I have something wrong in my tf configuration?

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-02-06**:
Can you update your question with the launch files you are using for both the sicklaser and rosaria launch. I am guessing problem with your tf. What do you get when you change the fixed frame in rviz to laser frame. Do you still see jumping?

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-07**:
No, when the fixed frame in rviz is set to laser, I don't see any jumping. The jumping around of laser readings only happens when I run the tf broadcaster node (see link of transform.cpp in above comments). I'm not using any launch files for sicklaser and rosaria. I'll write how I run the nodes.

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-07**:
This is what I mean by jumping around of laser readings: [laser jumps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dzkicsnshdyd25/laser_jumps.png?dl=0)

and this is the "duplicated map" that is produced as a result: [duplicate map](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6sp8xpvdzhp6me2/duplicate%20map.png?dl=0)

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-02-08**:
Can you share the bag file?

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-11**:
I was not recording bag files because I was running it and building the map in real-time...does that make a difference? The slam_gmapping algorithm can be run in real time, right? In any case I will record and share a bag file of the readings maybe you can help me identify what's wrong.

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-02-11**:
I think I solved the issue of laser readings jumping around. I changed the ros Rate to run to 100Hz. I have now produced a map of a corridor. It's a bad map of a corridor but to be fair I was driving the robot quite fast. [Bag](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yze183kwqs7t0s/mylaserdata.bag?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have the same problem as described in your question: In Rviz it says :" no map received". Did you solve your problem. Would you tell how did you do please.
Best regards

---

Originally posted by [RoSSy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22597/rossy/) with karma: 36 on 2015-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-06-01**:
Do you have a transform running between the laser and base_link? I had that missing and after I implemented it, it worked. You can check your transform tree by running rosrun tf view_frames.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-16**:
This answer should have been a comment to the question. Why is this marked as correct?